# Map for spring expression language

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I want to use SpEL to evaluate some predicates. Since the values/properties are dynamic, I don't have a certain bean class. Therefore, we have a hashmap where (according to the appliction state) the keys map to different POJOs/beans, e.g.:

```
Person person = new Person();// a person instance
person.setAge(25) // e.g. property age

Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<>();
model.put("person", person);    
// and others ...
```

We expected to use the Evaluation Context for this by setting the variables, like:

```
String predicate = "person.age>21";
StandardEvaluationContext context = new StandardEvaluationContext();
context.setVariables(model);
Expression expression = expressionParser.parseExpression(predicate);
boolean result = expression.getValue(context, Boolean.class);
```

But this throws an exception:

SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E:(pos 0): Property or field 'person' cannot be found on null

Anyone an advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the map is used in `setVariables()`, you need `#person.age > 21` since `person` is a variable.

Or you can set the map as the root object of the context.

```
context.setRootObject(model);
```

Or forget the context and pass the root object to the evaluation

```
expression.getValue(model, Boolean.class);
```

Comment: the # did it. 
Without the context does not work (throws a "property cannot be found on object of type 'java.util.HashMap' - maybe not public" exception)

Comment: Ah - right - you need an evaluation context with a `MapAccessor` added to its propertyAccessors.