# Spring integration expression map access with dot notation

Tags: spring-integration, spring-el

Normally in Spring EL you access a map entry by its key using the key in square brackets. If the payload of a spring integration message is a `java.util.Map`, then

```
payload['mykey']
```

gives you the value of the entry having the String 'my-key' as key.

When using the standard Spring EL setup, e.g. in a unit test, that is the only way to work with the map. However, in expressions used by Spring integration flows I can use the dot notation for map access. This works:

```
payload.mykey
```

I want to be able to use the same Spring EL expressions both in unit tests and route definitions. What makes the dot notation possible in Spring integration? Do I have to apply some special option to the EL parser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer at [Map for spring expression language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43967629/map-for-spring-expression-language). I need to add a http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/expression/MapAccessor.html to the evaluation context.

Comment: Also see http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/spel.html for more info what Spring Integration does underneath for its SpEL support.

Comment: The pointer to the Spring integration SpEL support is very helpful, thank you!

Comment: Good. Anyway I'm sure you can accept your own answer