# retrieve property on map using thymeleaf with spring

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

Whenever I'm using thymeleaf with spring, I find that I can retrieve a property on a map using "." (such as myMap.field). I want to know why it works. Because thymeleaf using spring expression language, and I should use "[]"(such as myMap['field']) on a map.
Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you can access it using dot operator like myMap.field, It is basically the implementation of Map for use when building model data for use with UI tools. Supports chained calls and generation of model attribute names.
This class serves as generic model holder for Servlet MVC but is not tied to it.

So **ModelMap**: implements Map interface. It also contains Map method.

When the variable is on the left side of the dot, it’s either a Map (something with keys) or a bean (something with properties).
This is true regardless of whether the variable is an implicit object or an attribute.
The thing at the right, the field name is basically the map property or key.

for more details
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/ui/ModelMap.html

https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/head-first-servlets/9780596516680/ch08s23.html

https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html#dynamic-fields

Answer (score 0):

the answer is like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45512177/spring-integration-expression-map-access-with-dot-notation)!. 
add a MapAccessor to evaluation context to use "." on map